# javascript cookie problem

Tags: javascript

I am very new to javascript.

Today I tried this function which I found on the Internet:

```
function get_cookie ( cookie_name )
{
    var cookie_string = document.cookie ;
    if (cookie_string.length != 0) {
        var cookie_value = cookie_string.match (
                        '(^|;)[\s]*' +
                        cookie_name +
                        '=([^;]*)' );
        return decodeURIComponent ( cookie_value[2] ) ;
    }
    return '' ;
}
```

If I call this function once, it works; however if i call this function twice, it's not working.

```
function onLoadThis() {
    var t = get_cookie('t'); // if i add another one, not working
    var s = get_cookie('s');
    // more code
}
```

Both cookies exist. Is there any workaround to make it work, or can two variable merged in a cookie? Thank you for your help.

Comment: I'd recommend using jquery and jquery.cookie

Comment: how does document.cookie look like?

Comment: Yes, add `alert(document.cookie);` to the beginning of your function for test purposes.

Answer (score 1):

You could try instead a different regexp:

Not

```
var cookie_value = cookie_string.match (
                        '(^|;)[\s]*' +
                        cookie_name +
                        '=([^;]*)' );
```

But

```
var cookie_value = cookie_string.match (
                       '([^;]*)[\s]*' +
                       cookie_name +
                       '=([^;]*)' );
```